# Getting username from Linked tables using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a table called tblAuditRecord which one of the fields records the logged in users ID as the auditor.  Now when retrieving records for viewing I want to retrieve the actual username who completed the audit and not the user ID.  I have successfully managed to do this when viewing a single audit record, however I am struggling to get it to work to retrieve a list of the audits.

```
var tblauditrecord = db.tblAuditRecords.OrderByDescending(e => e.dateOfAudit)
```

The above line of code currently returns the list of the Audits (The tolist extension method is added at the point of the return view  line of code.

Can anyone advise how I can get the UserProfile table to get the UserName by matching the AuditorID with the UserId.

I tried to use the .include as the code below

```
var tblauditrecord = db.tblAuditRecords.Include(e => e.UserProfileGetUsername);
```

but got an error "An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code" which was directing to the InitialiseSimplemembershipAttribute.cs file from this line of code

```
LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
```

If anyone can provide a solution it would be great (I'm betting I am making this more complicated than it needs to be)

TABLE MODEL CODE ADDED BELOW

```
    [Table("tblAuditRecord")]
    public class tblAuditRecord
    {

        [Key]
        public int auditId { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime dateOfAudit { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string fleetNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string nonFleetNumber { get; set; }

        //public string auditType { get; set; }  check about this one
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string bodyShopName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string vehicleReg { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30)]
        public string vehicleMake { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string vehicleModel { get; set; }

        [StringLength(150)]
        public string vehicleAdditionalDetail { get; set; }

        public int numberOfDoors { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string vehicleMileage { get; set; }

        public int auditorID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfileGetUsername { get; set; }

        public string auditorSignature { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public Nullable<DateTime> dateOfSignature { get; set; }

        public bool machinePolished { get; set; }

        public bool vehicleDriven { get; set; }

        public string bodyShopContactName { get; set; }

        public string bodyShopSignature { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public Nullable<DateTime> dateOfBodyShopSignature { get; set; }

        public string additionalInformation { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<tblDamageLine> tblDamageLines { get; set; }



    }
```

USER PROFILE TABLE

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the tables (i.e. columns/keys etc.) so people can see the underlying data structure?

Answer (score 0):

> var query = from u in userprofiles
>             join a in audits on u.UserID equals a.auditorID
>             select u.UserName;

I don't know the fields of UserProfile, so they may be .userID if you're using the same naming scheme as in tblAuditRecord . Also the UserProfile may be tblUserProfile.

This code needs 2 variables, one of type UserProfile (userprofiles) and one of tblAuditRecord (audits) that have the whole table for each class. Then you perform an inner join based on matching ids and retrieve the value that you want (user names) from the resulting table.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, however I need to select all the fields from the audit table and the username from the userprofile table. I tried this way previously but it didn't filter through to my razor page.

Comment: OK then you need to do this:

Comment: If you want for every record in audits the respective username from  UserProfile, you should do: select new {a , u.UserName}; This way you're selecting the whole record a in audits related to a UserName. This will create an anonymous type, that contains an object of type audits and an object of type string (username) (sorry for double post, can't edit prev comment)

Comment: Thanks for that, sorry but could I ask how to add order by descending on to this. I have added this code but I keep getting an error             var tblauditrecord = (from u in db.UserProfiles join a in db.tblAuditRecords on u.UserId equals a.auditorID select new { a, u.UserName });
            tblauditrecord.OrderByDescending(e => e.a.dateOfAudit);

Comment: Simply add: orderby a.dateOfAudit descending before the select.

Comment: Thanks very much the code is great, although it is conflicting with my razor view with this error.  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`2[VehicleAudits2_v1.Models.tblAuditRecord,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[VehicleAudits2_v1.Models.tblAuditRecord]'.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't so much choice, it depends of what are you expecting for about the result :

```
var query = FROM
  u IN userprofiles 
  JOIN
  a in audits
  ON 
  u.UserID EQUALS a.auditorID 
  SELECT
  u.UserName,
  a.dateOfAudit,
  a.fleetNumber ,
  a.nonFleetNumber ,
  a.auditType, 
  a.bodyShopName,
  ...,
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by using  the .include in my controller class

```
var tblauditrecord = db.tblAuditRecords.Include(e => e.UserProfileGetUsername);
```

and in my audit table model I added the following

```
        public int auditorID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("auditorID")]
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfileGetUsername { get; set; }
```

in my razor view I then called the username like so:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserProfileGetUsername.UserName)
```